# Adding a json object as child of another object

Tags: json, go

I have a `sample.json` with this content:

```
{
  "foo": "a",
  "bar": "b"
}
```

but some times `foo` is an array of string:

```
{
  "foo": ["a", "b"],
  "bar": "c"
}
```

I want a json object of:

```
baz: {
    "foo": "a",
    "bar": "b"
}
```

or

```
baz: {
    "foo": "a",
    "bar": "b"
}
```

depending on the case if foo is string or array of string. Here is my code:

```
type sample struct {
    foo      interface{} `json:"foo"`
    bar      string      `json:"bar"`
}

type parent struct {
    sample
}

jsonFileBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("sample.json")
// var p parent // for baz
json.Unmarshal(jsonFileBytes, &sample)

// How to proceed from here?
```

Comment: Did you mean that foo can be string or array? If yes, then after parsing the JSON you can check the type of the value and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @AdilRaza: I don't care if `foo` is string or array of strings. I just want the whole object to be added as child of `baz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said you wanted is not a valid map/json, because it is missing a key:

```json
baz: {
  {
    "foo": "a",
    "bar": "b"
  }
}
```

You can validate json [here](https://jsonlint.com/?code=)

The following code:

```golang
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
)

type Sample struct {
    Foo      interface{} `json:"foo"`
    Bar      string      `json:"bar"`
}

func main() {
  var sample Sample
  jsonFileBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("sample.json")
  json.Unmarshal(jsonFileBytes, &sample)

  baz := map[string]Sample{
    "baz": sample,
  }

  fmt.Printf("%+v", baz)
}
```

will give you the following output:

```
map[baz:{Foo:a Bar:b}]
```

Notice how the `sample` map is contained within another map that has a `baz` key pointing to `sample`.

Comment: My bad. Fixed it to valid json.